# Header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'); header('Status: 404 Not Found');

Tags: http-status-code-404, http

При создании страницы 404 в заголовки часто посылают следующие данные

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Status: 404 Not Found
```

Первый заголовок понятен. А вот, что означает 2 и нужен ли он вообще?

Answer (score 1):

Это зависит от того, как сервер взаимодейтсвует с PHP. Для FastCGI нужно отправлять Status: ..., для других способов HTTP/1.1 ...:

```
$sapi_name = php_sapi_name();
if ($sapi_name == ‘cgi’ || $sapi_name == ‘cgi-fcgi’) {
    header(‘Status: 404 Not Found’);
} 
else {
     header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ‘ 404 Not Found’);
}
```

Comment: А почему так?